# div alignment based on the content

Tags: html, css

I want to design the layout like  below screenshot.

[image]

I tried to do this by using following code.

```
<div class="salesDiv">
        <div>
             Quarter To Date
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="self">830</a>
        </div>
        <div>
             <img src="~/Images/navigation-unit-actionplan.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="offtier">
            <span>OFF TIER2</span>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
     <div class="salesDiv">
        <div>
             Rolling 3 Month
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="self">835</a>
        </div>
        <div>
             <img src="~/Images/navigation-unit-actionplan.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="offtier">
            <span>National 852</span>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
```

css :

```
.salesDiv {
  width: 313px;
margin-left: 10px;
border: solid 1px gray;
border-radius: 4px;
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
}

.salesDiv > div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.offtier {
border-left-style: dotted;
background-color: green;
height: 20px;
width: 88px;

}
```

but it didn't give the same layout as like above screenshot. I want to do like above screenshot. What's going wrong? Please anyone look into this.

http://jsfiddle.net/zHLMS/

spacing also not good. I need equal spacing for all the content inside the border.

I need to maintain the same width for both the element.

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply

```
display: inline-block; 
float:right;
```

to the sales > divs and `float: right` to the `offtier` divs

[Here's the modified code](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/zHLMS/7/)

Comment: but its not like as per design screenshot provided myself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zHLMS/17/. check it if i give 1000 it's down. i need to maintain same width for both element

Comment: and also the spacing is not good.need equal spacing for all the content inside the border

Comment: That's because of the width of the `offtier` div. Try increasing it marginally from `88px` to `90px`. This should solve your problem as long as you use upto 4 digits.

Comment: thanks.but what about the spacing  ? content inside the border

Comment: @Amarnath what's your changes ? nothing improved.

Comment: @Amarnath am asking about top and bottom spacing of the content inside the border for both element

Comment: For the spacing to be uniform you'll need to specify fixed widths to each type of div. [Check out the final example](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/zHLMS/51/).

Comment: @Amarnath am asking about spacing on top and bottom  like padding it will give spacing around all the corners.how can i ? got my point.

Comment: @Amarnath http://jsfiddle.net/zHLMS/53/.look this. done spacing using padding but last element is not like as per design. that's what my problem.

Comment: @SivaRajini [Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/zHLMS/55/) This should solve your problem. And read my penultimate comment for more explanation on the solution.

Answer (score -2):

Try this....[Updated Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zHLMS/50/)

```
 .salesDiv {
  width: 313px;
margin-left: 10px;
border: solid 1px gray;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
height: 20px;
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
}

.salesDiv > div {
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.offtier {
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
background-color: green;
height: 20px;
width: 88px;
right:0;
position:absolute;
}
```

Good Luck..Enjoy